# Cohn localization examples

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, localization

I'm working on my master's thesis, part of which involves an exposition on Cohn localization. ([nlab discussion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+localization))

In *Free ideal rings and localization in general rings*, Sec 7.4, Cohn gives a construction for a ring $\Sigma^{-1}R$. Given a set of matrices $\Sigma$ (with a mild closure condition), this ring admits a homomorphism from $R$ which is universal with respect to the property that the image of each matrix in $\Sigma$ is invertible over $\Sigma^{-1}R$.

I understand the construction and its uses in finding conditions for embeddability of domains into skew fields and the existence of universal fields, but I would really like to have some concrete examples of what the construction actually gives.

There are a few trivial examples - if $R$ is commutative, then $\Sigma^{-1}R$ is just the ring of quotients of $R$ with denominator set comprised of the determinants of matrices in $\Sigma$. If $\Sigma$ contains the zero matrix, the Cohn localization is the zero ring.

But neither of these highlights what makes Cohn localization a novel idea or sheds any light on what "matrix inverting homomorphisms" look like away from the commutative case.

Cohn's book also lacks examples. Where else can I see some concrete and informative examples of the ring $\Sigma^{-1}R$?

Comment: Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring, and let $M$ be some $n\times n$ matrix over $R$.  Universally inverting $M$ consists of first passing to the free product ring $R \ast_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}\langle u_{i,j}\, :\, 1\leq i,j\leq n\rangle$, and then factoring out the ideal of relations that forces the matrix $(u_{i,j})$ to be the inverse of $M$.  Knowing what elements belong to that ideal is, in general, very difficult to determine (without commutativity, even for a single matrix).  Cohn's closure conditions are designed to try to simplify those considerations, but generally it is still difficult.

Comment: That said, to get an explicit example, take your favorite ring $R$ and your favorite matrix $M$, and first figure out the free product above, and then explicitly work out the ideal of relations.

Comment: You might also look up Leavitt path algebras, as some of those algebras are examples of this universal inversion.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I'd honestly say that your method with infinte presentation is totally hopeless and provides zero insight on what localization result will be. If you are localizing at matrices invertible in a quotient ring, then there's a method by Vogel that realizes localization as a certain subring in adic completion (under some conditions, of course). There's one example of that approach in Vogel&Farber article "The Cohn localization of the free group ring" and other in "Cohn localization of finite group rings".

Comment: @DenisT. It's not totally hopeless in the infinite presentation case, if there is a reduction system in the sense of Bergman.  That said, it is much easier in the finite presentation case---but even there the localization is not easy.  (I doubt it even has to be finitely presented in general.)  When I said "Take your favorite ring" that was a bit tongue-in-cheek, because it might not be his favorite ring anymore, after trying that computation.  But it is worth giving it a try, just to see the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Cohn localization of group ring of free group on $r$ generators $k[F_r]$ w.r.t. set of matrices which are invertible after augmentation $\epsilon$ is the ring of "noncommutative rational functions", if $k$ is PID. To define what that "rational functions" are, recall that free group ring is embedded into formal series ring $\Gamma_r := k\langle\langle x_1, \dots, x_r \rangle \rangle$ via Magnus homomorphism

$$\mu: k[F_r] \to k\langle\langle x_1, \dots, x_r \rangle \rangle; \, x_i \mapsto 1 + x_i + x_i^2 + \dots.$$

Now consider set of $(\epsilon, Id)$-derivations $\delta_i$ on $\Gamma_r$ which send $x_iw$ to $w$ and $x_jw$ to $0$. They and their composites constitute a ring of operators $D := k[\delta_1, \dots, \delta_r]$ acting on $\Gamma_r$ Now, a rational function is an element $s$ of $\Gamma_r$ for which $Ds$ is a finitely generated $k$-module. One can readily check that the set of rational functions is closed under multiplication; if $r = 1$ that will result in usual rational functions ring.

What makes Cohn localization "novel", as you say? Free group rings do not satisfy Ore condition, so there's no way to construct this ring via usual method of "ring of fractions".